# Convert string to double or any numerical type variable in C#

Tags: c#, string, double

I've got a program that reads xml files. I already have a code that reads specific elements and places it in a variable. The only thing missing is comparing an element(a number) to a double variable, but elements are considered as string. All I have seen in Google is conversion of double to string. How do you convert a string to double?

EDIT:

I've got it now, I can't answer my own question yet 'coz I still have low reputation. This is what I've come so far and it works:

```
string stringNum = "2";
double value = double.Parse(stringNum);
```

Comment: `double.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not doing a great job in researching earlier.. I've got it now:

    string stringNum = "2";
    double value = double.Parse(stringNum);

Comment: @CodesInChaos, thanks for the code but I have to keep it simple and not add CultureInfo. I've already got the answer. Thanks! I just can't post my answer because I still have low reputation

Comment: I *strongly* recommend specifying a culture. Else your code will stop working when run on a German (for example) computer.

Comment: I'm with @CodesInChaos on the Culture bit. It's common practice to specify the Culture when using ToString or Parse methods. See:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182189(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var number = double.Parse("2.5", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[See Double.Parse at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse.aspx)

And just as a heads-up, you will probably want to take a look at `Parse(String, IFormatProvider)`, because parsing XML means you will have to look into the format of your "number strings". It's common practice to specify the `CultureInfo` when using `ToString` or `Parse` methods. [Look here for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182189%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

> When a CultureInfo or System.IFormatProvider object is not supplied,
>   the default value supplied by the overloaded member might not have the
>   effect that you want in all locales. Also, .NET Framework members
>   choose default culture and formatting based on assumptions that might
>   not be correct for your code. To ensure the code works as expected for
>   your scenarios, you should supply culture-specific information.

Comment: I was just adding the IFormatProvider bit you Ninja :)

Comment: @CodesInChaos Thank you for your clarification of the down vote. I've incorporated the InvariantCulture into my answer. And yes you are quite right that culture is a recommended practice in using Parse methods and one of my more favorite FxCop rules.

Comment: +1 now that the culture issue is fixed. | You should change the name of your variable, so it isn't a keyword.

Comment: Quite right. Fixed. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Double.Parse`, the 2nd parameter specifies the culture of the numbers in your file.

```
var newDouble = Double.Parse(theString, new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

Comment: or `TryParse`.  `Double.Parse` will throw an exception if the string is not a valid `double` representation.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain yourself?

Comment: Same reason as for the other downvotes, lack of culture. Now that it's fixed, I revoked it. (Though EN-GB is certainly an unusual choice compared to `InvariantCulture`)

Comment: @CodesInChaos I suppose it all depends on how the values in the file are formatted.